# Meaning of Uchimuhurdhal

Tags: vedas, puranas, advaita, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

I've heard this word many time -"Uchimuhurdhal"

I'm not sure whether I am spelling it right?
But I have heard this word , which might probably mean, "Elders doing uchimuhurdhal on young ones" - Kind of a blessing.

If anyone knows the meaning, can someone explain how its done, why and when it should be done?

Answer (score 1):

It refers to sniffing the head of a newborn baby during the Jatakarma ritual.

- `Uchchi` means peak.
- `Uchchi thalai` means peak of head.
- `mukarthal` means to sniff.

The technical term for that is `mUrdhani-avaghrANam`.

Source: Apastamba describes the Jatakarma ritual in the Grihya Sutra Patala 6.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me why it is done? Is it done only for new born baby? Should we tell any mantras while doing so?